# Extract and Separate the external CSS links into different txt files using python3

Tags: python, css, web-scraping

I have this code that extracts the CSS of a URL and outputs it in 2 different .txt files, internal and external.

How can I edit it in a way that it creates a separate file with the CSS content for each external URL link?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def page_Css(page_html):
    #find all the external CSS style
    external_css= page_html.find_all('link', rel="stylesheet")

    #find all the intenal CSS style
    internal_css =page_html.find_all('style')

    #print the number of Internal and External CSS
    print(f"{response.url} page has {len(external_css)} External CSS tags")
    print(f"{response.url} page has {len(internal_css)} Internal CSS tags")

    #write the Internal style CSS in internal_css.css file
    with open("internal_css.css", "w") as file:
        for index, css_code in enumerate(internal_css):
            file.write(f"\n  //{index+1} Style\n")
            file.write(css_code.string)

    #write the External style CSS links in external_css.txt file
    with open("external_css.txt", "w") as file:
        for index, css_tag in enumerate(external_css):
            file.write(f"{css_tag.get('href')} \n")
            print(index+1,"--------->", css_tag.get("href"))


#url of the web page
url = "https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/"

#send get request to the url
response = requests.get(url)

#parse the response HTML page
page_html = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

#Extract CSS from the HTML page
page_Css(page_html)
```

[image: 1]

Comment: What do you mean by "a separate file for each external URL link"? What should the contents of each of these "separate files" be?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, The content of each file should include the CSS of the external link. for example **file1.txt** would have all the CSS from the **first link** in the external link.txt . and **file2.txt** would have the CSS from the **second link** in the external link.txt.

Comment: Break this into smaller pieces. For example, given a string with a link for a css file, get it from the internet and write it to a file. Can you write a function to accomplish this task?